# Wilson Theorem in C++, incorrect output?

Tags: c++, proof, theorem

I have written a function that should check whether an integer is prime, using the Wilson theorem. However it outputs that 5 is not a prime number, which obviously is. I want to ask why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
long int counter = 1;
bool primeWilson(int n)
{
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        counter*=i;
    }
    if(n%(counter+1)!=0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note that the factorial you compute will quickly grow outside the range of an `int`, or any fundamental integral type in C++ for that matter. It's not a problem for 5, but it will almost certainly be for 20.

Comment: Apart from the logical problem, you probably want to move the initialisation of `counter` into the function, in case you want to call it more often than once. Maybe the whole definition can be moved.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the wrong way around for implementing Wilson.
For example:

25 is divisable by 5
but
5 is not divisable by 25

```
n%(counter+1)
```

->

```
(counter+1)%n
```